# How to check for gui vs command line mode in PySide2?

Tags: python, qt, qt5, pyqt5, pyside2

in my PySide2 code I need to check if the program is run in gui mode or command line. In PySide I used to do this:

```
if QApplication.type() == QApplication.Type.GuiClient:
    # do stuff
```

However, as per http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sourcebreaks.html:

> QCoreApplication::Type and QApplication::type() are removed. These Qt
>   3 legacy application types did not match the application types
>   available in Qt 5. Use qobject_cast instead to dynamically find out
>   the exact application type.

My PySide program is running inside a host application, so I am not creating a QCoreApplication instance myself, I just need to check if the host application is in batch mode (non GUI) or not to avoid some issues.

My question now is how to use [qobject_cast](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast) to achieve the same in PySide2?
The [C++ examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast) in the docs doesn't tell me much how to go about this with Python.

Could somebody please provide an example or advise on other ways to achieve the same thing?

Comment: There is no such mode in qt5, so there is nothing to check. All you can do is create a QCoreApplication or one of its subclasses, and you only need `isinstance` to see which one it is.

Comment: I failed to provide one bit of info, sorry: my PySide app is running within a host application which can be run in either GUI or command line mode (for batch processing). My PySide app needs to identify which one the host application is currently in to avoid issues. In other words I am not creating a QCoreApplication instance at all.

Comment: Though I see your point. Looks like I can just check if QtWidgets.QApplication.instance() is a QApplication or a QCoreApplication to differentiate. I will test this some more but this looks like the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end all I needed to do was:

```
isinstance(QtWidgets.QApplication.instance(), QtWidgets.QApplication)
```

which returns True when in GUI mode and False when in command line/batch mode.
Thanks ekhumoro for pointing me in the right direction!